# angular-velocity Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: node.js, angularjs, velocity.js

I have no idea why the angular-velocity module is not initialized although I included all required scripts as written here (https://github.com/cgwyllie/angular-velocity)

Here is my HTML index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MyApp</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular.js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/velocity/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/velocity/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/velocity/angular-velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my app,js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['angular-velocity']);
```

By running this I am getting the following error in chrome console.

```
Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] .....
```

Can someone please explain to me why this module cannot be initialized ?

Comment: check if all of your scripts files are loading correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular-velocity depends on ngAnimate module (see https://github.com/cgwyllie/angular-velocity/blob/master/angular-velocity.js#L6 ), unfortunately it is not mentioned on the project page.

Download and add reference to angular-animate.js (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngAnimate) in your page, ie :

```
<script src="lib/angualar.js/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

or when using bower call

```
bower install angular-animate
```

and add

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

to your page.

Comment: It would be nice, if you provided more source examples or added the link on a resource you'd got this information

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider switching to the official unofficial angular plugin for Velocity: https://github.com/rosslavery/velocity-ui-angular

Comment: I reviewed both of them, the angular-velocity has a few more features.